Get path of video/audio-file in fluid variable in Typo3
I really have a problem:
I have to set a video into my webpage with Typo3 (version 13.2) via the "Text&Media"-field, which doesn't work so far.
When I choose the video over the "media" tab, it is not shown on my webpage after a saved everything.
My questions now are: what am I doing wrong? I actually was trying to store the path to the video in a fluid variable in my typo-script, so that it then can be written to the src-attribute of a regular HTML-video-tag.
But, for me as a newbie to Typo3, I have no idea how to do that.
Here is my typoscript:
lib.fluidAudio = FILES
lib.fluidAudio {
  source.data = current:46
  table == tt_content
}

page = PAGE
page {
  meta.author = BOK&Gaertner
  meta.description = Station3
  meta.viewport = width=device-width, initial-scale=1

  12 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  12 {
    file = fileadmin/templates/station3.html
    layoutRootPath = /fileadmin/templates/Layouts/
    partialRootPath = /fileadmin/templates/Partials/
    variables {
      pagetitle < styles.content.get
      pagetitle.select.where = colPos=0

      # Übergeben des extrahierten Dateipfads an die Fluid-Variable "video"
      video = FILES
      video {
        references {
          table = tt_content
          fieldName = media
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
          10 = TEXT
          10.data = file:current:publicUrl
          10.wrap = |
        }
        maxItems = 1
      }

      maintext < styles.content.get
      maintext.select.where = colPos=2
    }
  }

  includeCSS {
    css = /fileadmin/templates/styles/styles.css
    css1 = /fileadmin/templates/styles/station3styles.css
  }
}

And here is the HTML-code snippet
  <div class="audio-player-top flex" onclick="showPlayAudio()">
                <p>Text anhören</p>
                <img src="./images/speaker.svg" alt="" class="speaker">
            </div>
            <f:debug>{lib.audioFile}</f:debug>
            <div class="audio-player-bottom">
                <audio src="/fileadmin/templates/audio/Station_3_Frage_1_mono.flac" controls></audio>
            </div>

What I want is just to place a video at a certain spot on my page (maybe via a variable).
But my concern is that I don't find any tutorials for especially Typo3 version 13 so I would be very grateful for any kind of explanation for what tables etc. are, where to find them and how to edit those files to embed the video...
The end of the story is now that I simply pasted the file-path hard into the src-attribute of the video-tag so that at least one can see the video.
But surely that's far beyond from how it has to be, because that video has to be replaceable by another without editing something in the typo-sript.
You have to be able to replace a.mp4 by b.mp4 so that b.mp4 is automatically on the page instead of a.mp4
Thank you very much already for helping me! :-)
JTR
I tried to set the Text&Media-field to a variable via video.select.where in hopes of linking the T&M-field to the variable and then somehow extracting the filepath from out of that variable.

The path should be usable via {video} in the template.

Hi Julian!
And what exactly should I try?

'Übergeben des extrahierten Dateipfads an die Fluid-Variable "video"' should work. But currently, you are not using this variable in your template.

@JulianHofmann Oh, my bad, here is the video-snippet
        <video src="{video}" type="video/mp4"></video>
        <video src="{video.publicUrl}" type="video/mp4"></video>

But unfortunately, it does not work. How can I extract the filepath of the video into a variable in my typoscript so that I can set as value of the src-attribute?
Thanks again for a reply!
JTR

In your TypoScript snippet, you pass already the path/ (=publicUrl) to the template. In your template, you're using video as an array... Have a look in video via <f:debug>{video}</f:debug>.

@JulianHofmann I did, and the debugger only said NULL. As if no video was found, but I actually selected it from the backend myself...
